# How to select class from div in jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have a code

```
protected void getBlogStats(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String result;
            Document document = null;
            try {
                document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                sendMessage("Error");
            }
            if(document == null) return;
            Elements nodeBlogStats;
            nodeBlogStats = document.getElementsByClass("div#name");
            if(nodeBlogStats.size() > 0) {
                result = nodeBlogStats.get(0).text();
            } else {
                result = "Error";
            }
            sendMessage(result);
        }
    }).start();

}
```

but how I can select class the tag div without id? 
For example, I have code:

```
<div id="detail-now" class="detail-tab-panel night">
Text
<div class="cond">Text</div>
</div>
```

And I want display data from class="cond".

I try fix it ArrayList String, but it was a fiasco. Maybe someone know how fix it problem?

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail? What are you trying to achieve? Why don't you want to use `div#name`?

Comment: To add more details to your post use [edit] option.

Comment: So.. I need display class div element, not id div element. and I don't know how do it.

Comment: It would help if you can post a sample of the HTML that you try to parse

Comment: you need to replace `getElementsByClass("div#name")` by the actual class name...

Comment: no, it didnt work, unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [JSOUP CSS selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

```
Elements divs = document.select("div.cond");
for (Element div : divs){
  System.out.println(div.text());
}
```

If you need to use getElementsByClass, try this:

```
Elements condEls = document.getElementsByClass("cond");
```

Comment: but how can I make a choice between div and span with code 'Elements condEls = document.getElementsByClass("cond");'?

Comment: You can't directly. That is what the ```document.select()``` method is for. I would really recommend you read about CSS selectors in JSoup.. They are very powerful.